# Rotating animation based on prewiously obtained positions

Tags: android, animation, rotation

I need to rotate image by some fixed degree after each click on it. Im using this code:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:fillAfter="true"
     >
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="-45"
        android:duration="500"

        android:toYScale="0.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"/>
</set>
```

Also tried this:

```
ObjectAnimator imageViewObjectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(img,
                "rotation", 0f, 45f);

        imageViewObjectAnimator.setDuration(1000); 
        imageViewObjectAnimator.start();
```

But every time animation starts from its initial position, ignoring positions that was obtained by prewiosly animation. So, -  how basicaly keep spining the image in one direction by 45 degrees after each click???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using a matrix to rotate an `ImageView`? Here's some sample code I pulled from an old app of mine:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
matrix.postRotate((float) angle, pivotX, pivotY);
imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

Just add an `onTouchListener` to the `ImageView`, define the first 2 lines outside of it and the last 2 inside the listener. Then every time you press, it will rotate by the pivot amount.

Comment: Thanks. Already find other solution. RotateAnimation rotateAnim = new RotateAnimation(rotationValue, rotationValue+=rotationStep,
                        RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                        RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);    It works;))

Comment: Oh, that's pretty sick, nice one!